# Rude tab keeps coming to the front

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-4.5, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl that uses the following XAML.

```
<TabControl x:Class="MyApp.Tab.TabContainer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Tab"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">

<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="5000"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="glowColor" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="glowMask" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="NewTabHeaderTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:AddNewTab}">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="+" FontSize="18" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MapTabHeaderTemplate" DataType="local:ACTabItemTabItem">
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Name="btn_TabDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btn_TabDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                <Image Source="icon_grey_cross.gif" Height="9" Width="9" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="bdr_main" Margin="4" BorderThickness="0" >
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,4,4,4" ContentSource="Content" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource glowColor}"></Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="OpacityMask" Value="{StaticResource glowMask}"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

```
public class AddNewTab : TabItem {}
```

During the constructor I do this to produce a blank tab with a simple '+' in the header.

```
_tabItems = new ObservableCollection<ACTabItem>();
try
{
    AddNewTab tabAdd = new AddNewTab();
    tabAdd.HeaderTemplate = this.FindResource("NewTabHeaderTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    _tabItems.Add(tabAdd);
}
this.DataContext = _tabItems;
```

When the user clicks the '+' I create a new TabItem and add it to the Items collection. I then attempt to bring the new tab to the front. (ImplementTab() simply creates a new TabItem with some values preset by the contents of 'td').

```
//code up here just collects some data from user to populate 'td'

TabItem newTab = ImplementTab(td);

if (newTab != null)
{
    _tabItems.Add((ACTabItem)newTab);
    newTab.Focus();
}
```

If I watch the this_SelectionChanged() event handler I see that the Focus() call does cause a change in SelectedIndex to the index of the newly added tab, but I also see that after the method the new tab code is in completes (right after the Focus()), SelectionChanged is thrown again, but this time with a SelectedIndex of '0' (the original blank tab with the '+' header).

Clicking on a tab throws SelectionChanged only once and I get the expected results.

I am simply trying to have the TabControl focus on a newly added TabItem...  how did I mess that up?

Comment: When your controls start having personalities, its time to step away from the keyboard for a while. A long while :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you don't have to inherit your AddNewTab from TabItem if you do databind. It should be just any class, inheriting it from TabItem makes it confusing since TabControl will create a new TabItem to wrap around this data item so all the methods like Focus() on the tab you created will have no effect.

To select the last tab just set the SelectedIndex instead of calling Focus.

```
if (TabControl1.Items.Count > 0)
    TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.Items.Count - 1;
```